# How to run Node js in React Native App after generating the Apk?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-native, express

I am currently using Express and Node js as my backend for my react native app. Right now i need to run my node js server if i want my react app to access the backend and my REST API. I wanted to know how can i run node js in my react app after i extract the apk file. How will others be able to use my app on their networks. How to run the node js server remotely.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you misunderstand a few concepts:

- You don't run the api server from the client. The server must already be running if you want to access it from the client
- If you want others to use this api with their clients, you should be running your api server in a public env (instead, or along with your dev env) so it will be accessible to clients from around the world

Comment: i understand your first point . In your second point i want to know how to run my node api server in public env

Comment: You need to run it through a server with public access to the port the node is running at.
For example I run my server application (written with node) on port 8080, so I open a firewall rule to allow incoming traffic for port 8080 on the server.